# Geofence pending intent firing too late when device is in deep sleep (doze) mode

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-geofence

I need to notify user when he is near by given place. I use Geofencing API for this. When i test app on Android emulator with mock location everything works fine. Same for real device with Mock Location. But when I walk and my phone is in deep sleep mode Geofence fires after 5 - 10 min. If i am inside geofences radius and I unlock my phone, open any app which use location my geofence triggers immediately. (Android 5.1, Motorolla moto G 1-st generation)

Below is the way, how I registered my geofence:

```
  public void registerLocation(RegisterAlarmRequestModel data) {
    if (isLocationDetectionAllowed() && isConnected) {
        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = prepareGeofencingRequest(prepareGeofence(data));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = prepareIntent(data.getId());
        PendingResult<Status> result = GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient, geofencingRequest, pendingIntent);
        Status status = result.await();
        if (status.isSuccess())
            Log.d("Location", "Geofence " + data.getId() + " has been registered");
    }
}

//preparing Geofence Pending Intent which will be triggered 
private PendingIntent prepareIntent(int alarmId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationRingingService.class);
    intent.putExtra(LocationRingingService.KEY_ALARM_ID, alarmId);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private GeofencingRequest prepareGeofencingRequest(Geofence geofence) {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofence(geofence);
    return builder.build();
}

private Geofence prepareGeofence(RegisterAlarmRequestModel data) {
    Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(String.valueOf(data.getId()))
            .setCircularRegion(data.getLatitude(), data.getLongitude(), data.getRadius())
            .setLoiteringDelay(100)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .build();
    return geofence;
}
```

For receiving intent I am using IntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Location", "accepted intent: " + intent.toString());
    //database request
}
```

This is how i have registered my service in manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".plugin.delivery.ringing.location.service.LocationRingingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

**Update:** I need catch the moment when user just entered into geofence as accurate as possible. I have one idea: register geofence with radius greater than need (for example if need 100m radius, register geofence with 200-300m radius). And when user enters into Geophence with larger radius -  start service with location udating to improve geofencing precision. And when user just entered - disable location service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve it, Let's perform some checks

1) Use broadcast receiver to get it triggered easily instead of service. And set priority with intent-filter.

For e.g

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".youpackage.GeoReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="yourpackage.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And your pending intent will be :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("yourpackage.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                youractivity,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

2) As your GPS goes in sleep mode, we need to wake it up while creating Geofence. Once you create your geofence, you can start pinging your GPS until you will get ENTER transition. This would must help to get triggering it.

```
public class GPSService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    public GPSService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
     // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();


     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();

     mGoogleApiClient.connect();
  }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     Utility.ReadAndWriteData(this, Utility.readFileName(this), "Still Geofence is not triggered!!!");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
      locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,locationRequest,this);

    }

   @Override
   public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)   {

  }

     @Override
     public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();

        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

       }
 }
```

And **don't forgot to stop this service immediately when you get ENTER transition** or It cause drain battery. This service is only to wake GPS up from sleep mode.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer! will try it. Have a nice day :)

Comment: unfortunately that advice isn't solves my problem :(

Comment: @user3383871 : It should be work! Could you explain me bit in detail what did he do? Took receiver instead of service first?

Comment: @user3383871 : Hey, I updated my answer! I also created service for second check. Check it. this time you will achieve it for sure :)

Comment: It's really works fine, thank you! But that solution is not suitable for my app, because geofencing should monitor location long time, it might be distance between two cities for example. I fear that it will be detrimental effect on battery life

Comment: @user3383871 : No, it won't because once you will create geofence as soon as ENTER transition will be called only one time if GPS will be on mode. And we are already shutting down service after getting first location. So you don't need to worry about battery as I already used it with many different scenarios. It's working perfect! :)

Comment: Thank you! you saved my day! :)

Comment: @Jai Hey buddy, i am triggering enter and exit both event, i am getting location at every 10 min. 
 My issue is i can not get accurate event. i have checked if the tiggered location accuracy more then 100 i consider as a dummy event and i am ignoring. is there any way to get all event on or 2 3 minutes delay. its travel time on road events.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when your phone is in deep sleep it is not updating the location accurately. The most accurate way to update location is GPS, and this is also the most battery-intensive. Other ways to update your location, such as using the cellular network, will consume less battery but are also less accurate. By default, geofences want to be really sure you are in the geofence before sending the intent. It is hard to get this sort of accuracy when in deep sleep because the phone is not getting accurate location data.

The reason why the geofence triggers immediately when you unlock your phone and use a location-aware app, is that the app updates the [LastLocation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), which your geofence sees and then sends the intent. While your phone is in deep sleep the location is not being updated.

With geofences there are also a few settings you can tweak to improve responsiveness. I see you're already using `setLoiteringDelay`, try playing around with different values , maybe try very small values and see what happens. You could also set a value for `setNotificationResponsiveness`, which works in a similar way. Doing that should make your fence more responsive, but it may cost more battery life. Also read the API Reference for [setLoiteringDelay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder#setLoiteringDelay(int)) and [setNotificationResponsiveness](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder#setNotificationResponsiveness(int)). Also read the [geofence troubleshooting](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#Troubleshooting) section if you haven't.

You could also increase the size of the geofence, try doubling it and then test. Since your location accuracy is low while in deep sleep, this will make it easier for your phone to be sure that it is inside the geofence, and once it's sure it is inside the geofence it will send the intent.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for detailed answer! You explained many obscure moments! I think i need update my question for good understanding of my problem.